# Select Data Based on Column Less Than Current Date and Empty Columns

Tags: php, mysql, date, inner-join, intervals

For example, i have two tables like this

Table User:

[image]

Table Payment:

[image]

I want to join two table above, but i want to get the result as quantity, 
How many of blanks **price** columns based from previous of current date.

So if current date is 2015-04-10, the result will be look like this:

[image]

I don't have any clue how to do that using some syntax query combination in SQL or in PHP to display the result

Comment: makes no sense mate, what is result? Write some pseudo-code so it makes sense

Comment: I mean, results of the number of blanks columns based from "price". So i will know how many of empty columns from "price" column

Comment: Ye i get that, but how come user_d got 2 results. Also would be nice if you could explain what a "previous current date" is, that would be interesting.

Comment: From my example above, if current date is 2015-04-10, of course user_d only got 2 because user_d have only 2 blank columns based from last_pay columns

Comment: I think you are after this: SELECT user.user_name, count(price) AS result FROM user
JOIN table_payment ON user.id_user = table_payment.id_user
WHERE table_payment.last_pay < '2015-04-10'
GROUP BY user.id_user

Comment: I've got the result user_c = 4, and user_d = 3 .. :(

Comment: So you only want prices that are empty? I didn't include that part

Comment: CamelToe did you check my solution below? I think it works :)

Comment: @raviolicode ye that works if the data is null, if its a empty string it wont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT user_name, COUNT(name) AS result
FROM user
JOIN payment ON users.id = payment.id_user
WHERE (price IS NULL OR ltrim(price) = '') 
  AND payments.last_pay < '2015-04-10'
GROUP BY payment.id_user
```

You can see the result of this query in the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/470522/7).

Comment: wrong, that would mean user_d would have 3 results and in his example user_d only had 2.

Comment: If "previous of current date" means `last_pay` earlier than `current date` then the last line should use `<`?

Comment: @FrankBoyne that is correct, took me a while to figure out "previous current date" since i never heard those words in the same sentence.

Comment: It work very well, thx a lot raviolicode .. @CamelToe yeah previous current date is a strange sentence, because my main language is not english so i'm really confused how to say that in english